# Plotting images from array containing datatype UInt8

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I have a bunch of images (of cats) and want to plot one of them. The values image are in the format `UInt8` and contain 3 bands. When I try to plot using plots I get the following error, `ERROR: StackOverflowError`.

```
 Using Plots

# Get data
train_data_x = fid["train_set_x"] |> HDF5.read
#Out >
3×64×64×209 Array{UInt8, 4}:
[:, :, 1, 1] =
0x11  0x16  0x19  0x19  0x1b  …  0x01  0x01  0x01  0x01
0x1f  0x21  0x23  0x23  0x24     0x1c  0x1c  0x1a  0x16
0x38  0x3b  0x3e  0x3e  0x40     0x3a  0x39  0x38  0x33
...

# Reshape to be in the format, no_of_images x length x width x channels
train_data_rsp = reshape(train_data_x, (209,64,64,3))

# Get first image 
first_img = train_data_rsp[1, :, :, :]

plot(first_img)
Out >
ERROR: StackOverflowError:

# I also tried plotting one band and I get a line plot
plot(train_data_rsp[1,:,:,1])
#Out >
```

[image]

Any ideas whats incorrect with my code?

Comment: You may want to load ImageIO to show the images rather than plot them with Plots.  You may also need to check your image file storage format to be sure your reshape does not mix the images together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd be careful about how you're `reshape`ing; I think this will merely rearrange the pixels in your images instead of swapping the dimensions, which it seems like you want to do. You may want `train_data_rsp  = permutedims(train_data_x, (4, 2, 3, 1))` which will actually swap the dimensions around and give you a `209×64×64×3` array with the semantics of which pixels belong to which images preserved.

Then, Julia's [`Images`](https://juliaimages.org/latest/) package has a [`colorview`](https://juliaimages.org/latest/tutorials/conversions_views/#Using-colorview-to-make-color-overlays) function that lets you combine the separate R,G,B channels into a single image. You'll first need to convert your array element type into [`N0f8`](https://juliaimages.org/latest/tutorials/arrays_colors/#fixedpoint) (a single-byte format where 0 corresponds to 0 and 255 to 1) so that `Images` can work with it. It would look something like this:

```
julia> arr_rgb = N0f8.(first_img // 255)  # rescale UInt8 in range [0,255] to Rational with denominator 255 in range [0,1]
64×64×3 Array{N0f8,3} with eltype N0f8:
[...]
julia> img = colorview(RGB, map(i->selectdim(arr_rgb, 3, i), 1:3)...)
64×64 mappedarray(RGB{N0f8}, ImageCore.extractchannels, view(::Array{N0f8,3}, :, :, 1), view(::Array{N0f8,3}, :, :, 2), view(::Array{N0f8,3}, :, :, 3)) with eltype RGB{N0f8}:
[...]
```

Then you should be able to plot this image.